# setState(prev) returning previous state in reverse order than expected when referencing another useState var in a useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a simulated chat experience where at `obj4`, the user has a button to click to initiate their session.

Everything works fine showing messages 1-4 but when `messages.length === 4` and I check `initiated === true`, weird stuff starts happening: `prev`, which usually returns the messages in the correct order, now returns the messages in the *reverse* order. And calling `.reverse()` or setting `prev` to a new variable and *then* calling `reverse()` doesn't work either.

The whole order of messages breaks when I check `if (initiated === true)` but if I don't, everything renders in the order I expect.

Any idea what's happening here?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const chattest = () => {

    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    const [initiated, setInitiated] = useState(false)

    const obj1 = {
        type: 'text',
        text: '1',
        action: function() {}
    }

    const obj2 = {
        type: 'text',
        text: '2',
        action: function() {}
    }

    const obj3 = {
        type: 'text',
        text: '3',
        action: function() {}
    }

    const obj4 = {
        type: 'button',
        text: initiated ? 'Initiated!' : 'Initiate',
        state: initiated,
        action: function() {
            console.log('setting initiated')
            setInitiated(true)
        }
    }

    const obj5 = {
        type: 'text',
        text: 'initiated set!',
        action: function() {}
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        switch(messages.length) {
            case 0:
                setMessages([obj1])
            case 1:
                setMessages((prev) => [...prev, obj2])
            case 2:
                setMessages((prev) => [...prev, obj3])
            case 3:
                setMessages((prev) => [...prev, obj4])
            case 4:
                if (initiated) { // behavior changes here if I use this line 

                    setMessages((prev) => {
                        console.log('prev', prev)
                        console.log('prev reversed', prev.reverse()) // this doesnt work
                        return [...prev, obj5]
                    })
                }
            default:
                break
        }
    }, [messages, initiated])

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col-reverse border border-solid border-black-500 w-[50%] mx-auto h-screen text-black">
            {
                messages.reverse().map((message, index) => {
                    const { type, text, state, action } = message
                   return <div key={index}>
                        <ChatFactory type={type} state={state} _text={text} action={action} />
                    </div>
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default chattest

const ChatFactory = ({type,_text, state,action}) => {
    return (
        type === 'text'
        ? (
            <p>{_text}</p>
        )
        : (
            <button onClick={action}>
               { _text}
            </button>
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Your switch doesn’t have any breaks, but the rest of this code is really contrived looking. It’s not clear to me why is messages even state

Comment: I guess the answer to your immediate question is that you [mutated state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse). Don’t ever mutate state

Comment: @Adam Don't mutate state in the useEffect? Nice catch on missing the breaks. oof

Comment: Why is messages state here? The way I’m reading it, it will update messages on every single  render, because messages is a dependency of the effect and you update messages in the effect. Aside from array.reverse mutating state, why are you using it at all? This example looks really poor, I’m not sure if this really works, but it’s a very unidiomatic way to write react code

Comment: Thank @Adam. I understand it's probably not the best way to do it. What would you suggest as an alternative? To answer your question more directly, the goal of the UI is a simulated chat state where at certain points, the user clicks to trigger the next message but other than that, the automated chat on the other side is pushing messages in. That's why it's built like this but again, totally open to better ways to do this

Comment: From what you describe, messages should be state, but your current code doesn't do that. Your current code just rerenders the component until `messages` has 4 items. I think what you need is a [minimal reproducivle example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I typically use a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: @Adam here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-khyib7?file=pages%2Findex.js

Made some minor edits. Things seem to be closer to working than in my local environment. Tailwind isn't configured, maybe that's my issue locally. Here what I'm getting is 1, 2, <button> 4, without the incorrect reorder on click. I added the `break`s. Main issue here I needing to click the button twice to get the text value to change. Curious for your thoughts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251244/discussion-between-zack-shapiro-and-adam).

Comment: What’s supposed to happen when the user clicks the button? What (if anything) is supposed to triggers the automated chat to “send a message”? The final code will be drastically simpler than you think once you lay out the requirements

Answer (score 1):

You're mutating your state in this line:

```
messages.reverse().map((message, index)
```

**reverse()** method reverses an array in place and returns the reference to the same array. This means mutating the state directly which you shouldn't do..

And "**break;**" is missing in your switch statements

Also, using the array index as a key might lead to an unexpected behavior in the future.. Using the index as a key is the default behavior for React anyway..

Comment: using array indexes as keys is OK if you're not going to change order of items on UI
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html "We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change"

Comment: Thank you @Uladzimir for clarifying when indexes are not enough.. But he might add deleting messages to his app and that might lead to an unexpected behavior..

Answer (score 1):

The confusing behaviour of you code is the result of two things:

1. Object mutation.
2. `<React.StrictMode>`.

To make things easier to explain, comment out the following pieces of code.

In your `chattest` component, comment-out the following line:

```
// console.log('prev reversed', prev.reverse());
```

Assuming you are running this on a development server, comment-out the strict mode wrapper from your `index.js` file (or wherever it may be).

```
root.render(
  // <StrictMode>
  <App />
  // </StrictMode>
);
```

We will come back to the two previous pieces of commented out code later, but for now I'll explain your code's behaviour without considering them.

Running the code now, The `messages` array state renders in the following order:

[image: Initial page state]

This is the result of the following rendering process:

1. `chattest` mounts and renders with `messages` as an empty Array.
2. The `useEffect` hook in `chattest` has its callback invoked as it is the first render.
3. In the `switch` statement, `case 0` matches, and with no `break` clauses until the end of the switch statement, all the `setMessages` functions are invoked except the final one in `case 4`), as `initiated` is `false`.
4. As `setMessages` was invoked, a re-render is triggered with all the state setter callback functions stacking, effectively assigning `[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]` to `messages`.
5. On re-render, `messages` (`[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]`) is reversed before being displayed and is mutated at the same time (due to the behaviour of `.reverse()`), so `messages` now holds `[ob4, obj3, obj2, obj1]`.

It's important to note here that **direct mutations do not trigger renders in React**, so at this point, nothing else happens until the initiate button is clicked. Once the `initiate` button is clicked, the list should now look like the following:

[image]

This is the result of the following steps:

1. The initiate button is clicked, and `setInitiated` is called to assign `true` to `initiated`, also queuing a render.
2. A re-render occurs due to the call to `setInitiated`.
3. `messages` is reversed again, mutating the state back to `[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]`.
4. After `chattest` is rendered, because `initiated` has been updated and is part of the `useEffect`'s dependency array, the `useEffect` callback is invoked.
5. in the `switch` statement, `case 4` matches and with `initiated` being truthy, `setMessages` is invoked, which ques a re-render and sets `messages` to `[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5]`.
6. `chattest` re-renders and `messages` is reversed then displayed - mutating the state into `[obj5, obj4, obj3, obj2, obj1]`

Now comment back in your `console.log`:

```
console.log('prev reversed', prev.reverse());
```

When Refreshing the page with the console log included, the initial screen is the same. The change in behaviour happens when the initiate button is clicked:

[image]

This is the result of the following steps:

1. The initiate button is clicked, and `setInitiated` is called to assign `true` to `initiated`, also queuing a render.
2. A re-render occurs due to the call to `setInitiated`.
3. `messages` is reversed, mutating the state to `[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]`.
4. After `chattest` is rendered, because `initiated` has been updated and is part of the `useEffect`'s dependency array, the `useEffect`'s callback is invoked.
5. In the `switch` statement, `case 4` matches and with `initiated` being truthy, `setMessages` is invoked.
6. Within `setMessages`'s callback body, a `console.log` is invoked which logs `prev.reverse` and since **`prev` is a reference to the same array as `messages`**, the `messages` array state is effectively mutated to `[obj4, obj3, obj2, obj1]`.
7. The rest of the `setMessages` callback is executed and the `messages` state becomes `[obj4, obj3, obj2, obj1, obj5]`.
8. `chattest` re-renders and `messages` is reversed then displayed - mutating the state into `[obj5, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]`.

Introducing `<React.StrictMode>` back into the code results in your components and effects executing twice. You can probably already start to imagine how it would make the previous sequence of events more complicated. It can get particularly tricky in this instance because there will be cases where `.reverse` will seem like it is taking no effect at all when it is actually being invoked twice. Additionally, there will be other cases (like where your `map` function is implemented) where the amount of `.reverse` invocations will not necessarily be reflected in rendering, because as I mentioned earlier - **direct mutations do not trigger renders in React**. Ultimately, this will give the impression of inconsistent execution in your code, which is probably the primary cause for most of the confusion you describe in your question.

You might think the smart thing to do in this case is to remove the strict-mode wrapper from your application code - **do not do this**. `<React.StrictMode>` is there to help you write better components (primarily) and it doesn't have an effect in production anyway.

There are two things you should take away from all this:

1. Treat all React state objects as if they were immutable.
2. Write all your React components as pure functions.

Abiding by these two rules will allow you to avoid a whole class of baffling bugs that are incredibly tricky to debug. I would explain further, but the React docs do a terrific job of explaining these concepts (linked below).

With that being said, I am not entirely sure of what you are trying to do with your current implementation, but adhering to the two rules just mentioned - minor changes can be made to make the behaviour of your code more predictable.

Change the following code to incorporate the `spread (...)` syntax.

```
//...

console.log('prev reversed', [...prev].reverse()) // this doesnt work

//...

[...messages].reverse().map((message, index) => {

//...
```

Using the the `spread (...)` syntax in this way allows you to create anonymous shallow copies of an array. `.reverse()` behaves the exact same way, except it is mutating the anonymous copy of `messages`, not the original array that `messages` points to. This should fix the majority of your issues relating to the concepts mentioned here.

I also noticed that in `obj4`, you are using a Conditional (ternary) operator to try and render different text inside the initiate button. While `obj4` will correctly reflect the text on the render where `initiated` is `true`, the version of `obj4` inserted into the `messages` array is from a render where `initiated` was `false`. One way to resolve this is to assign a callback function to `obj4`'s `text` property:

```
text: (reactiveState) => reactiveState ? 'Initiated!' : 'Initiate',
```

Then pass `initiated` to the `chatFactory` component:

```
//...

<ChatFactory
  type={type}
  state={state}
  _text={text}
  action={action}
  initiated={initiated}
/>;

//...

const ChatFactory = ({ type, _text, state, action, initiated }) => {

//...
```

Then, instead of passing `_text` as the buttons inner text, invoke it as a function, passing in `initiated` as the argument:

```
//...

<button onClick={action}>{_text(initiated)}</button>

//...
```

The `switch` statement in the `useEffect` callback is also questionable, but I don't fully understand your implementation, so I wont go too deep into the details. Its worth mentioning a couple of things though.

While it seems like it would be sensible to add a `break` clause at the end of each case, in effect, it wouldn't make much difference here as it would still result in `oj1`, `oj2`, `oj3`, and `oj4` being inserted into the `messages` array almost immediately, except a re-render will now occur between each insert (which could also increase the impact of the existing component impurities).

Also, you're `useEffect` implementation includes `messages` in its dependency array. This means that any change to the `messages` state will cause the `useEffect` callback to be invoked. While it does not seem there are any un-intended effects now, just be aware that improper usage of the `useEffect` hook can cause issues that can be hard to debug and/or break your code. I only mention this because there are multiple `setMessages` invocations in your switch statement, so further development of this code could cause issues in the future if you're not careful.

Hope all this helps.

---

**Links:**

- [Learn more about mutating objects in React from the React documentation, here.](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state#whats-a-mutation)
- [Learn more about pure components in React from the React documentation, here.](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/keeping-components-pure)
- [Learn more about `<SrictMode>` in React from the React documentation, here.](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/StrictMode)

Comment: Amazing, super-comprehensive answer, Damon. Thanks for taking the time to explain things so thoroughly.

Comment: No worries. I found it really enjoyable piecing together the puzzle to be honest. Hope it helps others better understand the inner workings of React.

Comment: Thank you Damon! Really appreciate you taking the time here

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. So, as @Mohammad mentioned above, the trouble sits in this line:

```
 {messages.reverse().map((message, index) => {
```

.reverse mutates array (instead of returning a new one "reversed")

---

To quickly fix this issue, just clone the array of messages from state before reversing:

```
 {[...messages].reverse().map((message, index) => {
```

---

That's just a small ocasional bug with state object mutation. On the other hand what's definitely wrong with code above is that you utilize useEffect for "calculation purposes". useEffect was introduced by ReactJS team to implement interractions with 3rd-party services/non-react-Api/etc..., but for calculations in code it should not be used without very very stong reason on that (reacting on user click and new element addition in array is just a simple caclulation). Please reference this tremendous article from react team:
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect

The main reason on that - using effects for calculations cause additional re-render by ReactJS and impacts application performance for larger apps. Plus, from my point of view, it ruins code readability and it's "linear flow" in general

---

As an option, you could get rid of useEffect at all and perform messages array calculation just before returning JSX (commented several "old" lines of code and added several lines more just before return)

In this case you would not even need to clone messages array before reversing as far as it would not persist in state more "between" re-renders

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Chattest = () => {
    // const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [initiated, setInitiated] = useState(false);

    const obj1 = {
        type: 'text',
        text: '1',
        action: function () {},
    };

    const obj2 = {
        type: 'text',
        text: '2',
        action: function () {},
    };

    const obj3 = {
        type: 'text',
        text: '3',
        action: function () {},
    };

    const obj4 = {
        type: 'button',
        text: initiated ? 'Initiated!' : 'Initiate',
        state: initiated,
        action: function () {
            console.log('setting initiated');
            setInitiated(true);
        },
    };

    const obj5 = {
        type: 'text',
        text: 'initiated set!',
        action: function () {},
    };

    // useEffect(() => {
    //  switch (messages.length) {
    //      case 0:
    //          setMessages([obj1]);
    //      case 1:
    //          setMessages((prev) => [...prev, obj2]);
    //      case 2:
    //          setMessages((prev) => [...prev, obj3]);
    //      case 3:
    //          setMessages((prev) => [...prev, obj4]);
    //      case 4:
    //          if (initiated) {
    //              // behavior changes here if I use this line

    //              setMessages((prev) => {
    //                  console.log('prev', prev);
    //                  console.log('prev reversed', prev.reverse()); // this doesnt work
    //                  return [...prev, obj5];
    //              });
    //          }
    //      default:
    //          break;
    //  }
    // }, [messages, initiated]);

    const messages = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4];
    if (initiated) {
        messages.push(obj5);
    }

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col-reverse border border-solid border-black-500 w-[50%] mx-auto h-screen text-black">
            {messages.reverse().map((message, index) => {
                const { type, text, state, action } = message;
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <ChatFactory
                            type={type}
                            state={state}
                            _text={text}
                            action={action}
                        />
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Chattest;

const ChatFactory = ({ type, _text, state, action }) => {
    return type === 'text' ? (
        <p>{_text}</p>
    ) : (
        <button onClick={action}>{_text}</button>
    );
};
```